# For Loop not running within my get function

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to validate my data (PC_CODE in this case) by comparing the value it exist within my database which I created a custom function to retrieve the value from my database. The problem that I encounter is my custom function seems does not run it's for loop for some reason.

This is the custom function that I created to retrieve the data.

```
   Private Sub validatePccode()
        Try
            Dim command As New SqlCommand("SELECT PC_CODE FROM TAB WHERE PC_CODE = '" & pccode.Text & "'", conn)
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
            Dim ds As New DataSet

            da.Fill(ds)

            For y = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1

                If pccode.Text <> ds.Tables(0).Rows(y).Item(columnName:="PC_CODE") Then

                    isFalse = True
                    MessageBox.Show(isFalse)
                    MessageBox.Show("Structure not found. Please key in the correct specification code and make sure you created the structure.")
                    hideLabelAndField()

                    While isFalse = True
                        If pccode.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(y).Item(columnName:="PC_CODE") Then
                            isFalse = False
                            Exit While
                        End If
                    End While

                Else
                    isFalse = False
                End If

            Next

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

This is the Module that I created to connect my data

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Module ConnectionModule

    Public conn As SqlConnection
    Public cmd As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Public Function Get_Connect() As SqlConnection
        conn = New SqlConnection("Server=xxxxxxxxxx;Database=xxxxxxxxx;Trusted_Connection=true")
        Return conn
    End Function

End Module
```

This is the custom function where I placed (event trigger when user pressed the enter key)

```
Private Sub pccode_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles pccode.KeyDown
        Get_Connect()
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            checkEmptyString()
            validatePccode() <----------------------------------------- is here
            While isEmpty = False And isFalse = False
                If firstItem.Text = "" Then

                    firstLayerAvailable()
                    get_Data()
                    resetSearchField()
                    focusValueDay()
                    Exit While

                ElseIf secondItem.Text = "" Then

                    secondLayerAvailable()
                    get_Data()
                    resetSearchField()
                    focusValueDay()
                    Exit While

                ElseIf thirdItem.Text = "" Then

                    thirdLayerAvailable()
                    get_Data()
                    resetSearchField()
                    focusValueDay()
                    Exit While

                ElseIf fourthItem.Text = "" Then

                    fourthLayerAvailable()
                    get_Data()
                    resetSearchField()
                    focusValueDay()
                    Exit While

                ElseIf fifthItem.Text = "" Then

                    fifthLayerAvailable()
                    get_Data()
                    resetSearchField()
                    focusValueDay()
                    Exit While

                ElseIf sixthItem.Text = "" Then

                    sixthLayerAvailable()
                    get_Data()
                    resetSearchField()
                    focusValueDay()
                    Exit While

                ElseIf seventhItem.Text = "" Then

                    seventhLayerAvailable()
                    get_Data()
                    resetSearchField()
                    focusValueDay()
                    Exit While

                ElseIf eighthItem.Text = "" Then

                    eighthLayerAvailable()
                    get_Data()
                    resetSearchField()
                    focusValueDay()
                    Exit While

                ElseIf ninthItem.Text = "" Then

                    ninethLayerAvailable()
                    get_Data()
                    resetSearchField()
                    focusValueDay()
                    Exit While

                ElseIf tenthItem.Text = "" Then

                    tenthLayerAvailable()
                    get_Data()
                    resetSearchField()
                    focusValueDay()
                    Exit While

                End If
            End While
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: I've changed your code tag, as this looks to be a vb.net question. Change it back if you believe it's relevant to vba.

Comment: It's a terrible practice to do `Catch ex As Exception` (especially only with `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)` inside). You should let general exceptions bubble up.

Comment: There should be no "seems" about it. Either it does or it doesn't. If you haven't already - presumably you haven't - you need to debug your code. That means setting a breakpoint at the top and stepping through it line by line, examining the state at each step. It will be clear what happens then and, if the code doesn't behave as expected, you will be able to see exactly why. If you still can't work out how to fix it, at least you'll have far more relevant information to provide us with.

Comment: When iterating through collections like ds.Tables(0).Rows, you are far beter off using a For Each loop. For Each row in ds.Tables(0).Rows...  Much more reliable than relying on loop counters

Comment: Have you tried debugging it line per line? If your IDE isn't set to raise every issue you may be experiencing a "stealth crash" where a function returns too quickly because of a problem.